# binding sql data in jquery grid

Tags: sql, jqgrid

i am using a jquery grid in asp.net and c# ? is it possible for me to bind a sql table in to a jquery grid.
if so let me go through the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind sql statement to it.

You know, javascript is running at client side but binding at server side.
But a jQuery plugin named datatables(http://www.datatables.net/) used for showing data.

That plugin using its own data structure so you need make your table's data to fit it.
I think write your own data table version is faster than using datatables.

Gook luck

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations)
[And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442013/jquery-grid-for-asp-net-c)
[Here's another one](http://blueorbitsoftware.com/blog/?p=17)

The first one is very detail in which jquery grids plugins are out there. From there you can google like crazy and find a couple of interesting asp.net implementations. Not very clear (i'm in that process too) but they can help you a little bit.
The other too are more focus to your question.
Hope we find what we are looking for.